# How to plot ideals of rings

Tags: ring-theory, ideals, visualization

Im trying to better understand ideals of rings and I think being able to visualize what I'm working with would help. I want to graph them (I'm talking mostly about quadratic rings), but I don't know which program would be good for plotting ideals where multiple entries are required.

For example, trying to plot the ideal $(1+\sqrt{-5})$ of $Z[\sqrt{-5}]$ requires me to do all this in desmos (unless theres some other trick I dont know about)
[image]
But I really wish there was a program where I could more easily plot this. Any help appreciated!

Comment: This assumes your ring is a subset of $\mathbb R\times \mathbb R$.  In general I think it is more enlightening to draw the lattice of ideals by containment to make a Hasse diagram , rather than elements as points.